# I want to dynamically change the color of widget in grid Layout in kivy

Tags: python-2.7, opengl, kivy

I want to dynamically  change the color of a widget in grid layout.
How can i achieve that?
I create a widget matrix of 6x6 and i need to blink the tiles in the grid layout dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating grid widgets and then just change color of the widgets with a scheduled function . Below code might now be perfect but may help you :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random


class RootWidget(GridLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = GridLayout(cols=6)
        Colour=[0,0,0,0]
        self.create_button(parent,Colour,1,1)
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda a:self.update(parent), 1)
        return parent

    def update(self,obj):
        print "I am update function"
        obj.clear_widgets()
        print "random value is ",random.random()
        for i in (1,2,3,4,5,6):
            for j in (1,2,3,4,5,6):
                c=[random.random(),random.random(),random.random(),random.random()]
                d=[i,j]
                self.create_button(obj,c,i,j)

    def create_button(self,obj,color,i,j):

        a=Button(background_color=color,text='Hello World %s%s'%(i,j))
        obj.add_widget(a)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: This clears and recreates all the widgets each time, which is quite inefficient. It gives the right visual effect, but it would be a lot better to just reset the `background_color` of the buttons each time.

Comment: @inclement ... yeah that will be more efficient . it will be a loop like this in your update function def update(self,obj):
        print "I am update function"
        for child in obj.children:
            c=[0,random.random(),1,random.random()
            child.background_color=c