# I want to dynamically change the color of the text in a widget in grid layout

Tags: python, android-widget, widget, kivy

I want to dynamically change the color of the text in a widget in grid layout.
How can i achieve that? I create a widget matrix of 6x6 and i need to blink the tile's text in the grid layout dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very same as your older question 
[I want to dynamically change the color of widget in grid Layout in kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779185/i-want-to-dynamically-change-the-color-of-widget-in-grid-layout-in-kivy)

just in place of background_color use color property of button . Try code below :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random

class RootWidget(GridLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = GridLayout(cols=6)
        for i in (1,2,3,4,5,6):
            for j in (1,2,3,4,5,6):
                parent.add_widget(Button(text='%s%s'%(i,j)))

        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda a:self.update(parent),1)

        return parent

     def update(self,obj):
        print "I am update function"
        for child in obj.children:
            c=[0,random.random(),1,random.random()]
            child.color=c


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```